# Reacting to a click on a preference

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have a simple preference (not EditText preference or ListPreference). I have a method that deletes all files in a directory. I want to do this when user clicks on a preference, but i don't know how to react to a click on a preference.

Comment: Post some part of your code... that helps a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pref_key").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if your preference is stored in an object(`togglePref`) you can do this

```
togglePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```

then the event is:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

}
```