# Jump to Dialer or any default Caller App when clicking on a Preference item

Tags: android, android-preferences

My question is pretty closed to [reacting-to-a-click-on-a-preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085538/reacting-to-a-click-on-a-preference)

I want to use Intent + android:action in my R.xml.preferences file instead of setting up OnClickListener on a certain preference item as below

```
    <Preference android:title="@string/pref_cat3_call_center">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.DIAL"
            android:data="1112223333" />
    </Preference>
```

While I always encounter the exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=+1112223333}
```

Is this idea possible, or I have to use OnClickListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone apps support `Uri`'s in the form of `tel:XXX`.

Change your `android:data` value to `"tel:1112223333"`

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_DIAL

> Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number to be dialed **or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number**.

Comment: Thank you @marmor !